# Search and replace referring to list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have list which consists of search and replace values in it. I'm trying to iterate the list with string using for loop this causing re-replacing with other value. Any help would be appreciated.

Example : 
List

```
grp=["MEDICAL | MEDCL | MDCL | MEDICINE | MEDCL | ME | MEDICA | MDM | MEDI | M | MEDICIN | MEDIC | MEDICI / MED /"," CENTRA| CENTRE| CNTR| CTRS| CENTERS|CENTRAL | CENTER| CEN| CENT| CNTRS| CENTERR| CE| CT| CENTE| CENTERE / CTR /"," MAINE / ME /"]
```

Input:

```
str="CENTRAL MAINE MEDICAL CENTER"
```

Expected Output:

```
"CTR ME MED CTR"
```

Code Tried:

```
for i in range(len(grp)):
    res_split=re.findall(r"[^/]+",grp[i])
    for x in res_split[0].split("|"):
        str = str.replace(x,res_split[1])

str
```

Output:

```
' CTR R R R R MED  MED CTR R R R R '
```

Comment: Don't name strings `str`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regular expression here:

[`(?:SEARCH_WORD).*?\/\s*(\w+)`](https://regex101.com/r/OeU0gL/1)

Unfortunately you have to search once for each word, since otherwise you would have overlapping matches.

```
import re

grp=''.join(["MEDICAL | MEDCL | MDCL | MEDICINE | MEDCL | ME | MEDICA | MDM | MEDI | M | MEDICIN | MEDIC | MEDICI / MED /"," CENTRA| CENTRE| CNTR| CTRS| CENTERS|CENTRAL | CENTER| CEN| CENT| CNTRS| CENTERR| CE| CT| CENTE| CENTERE / CTR /"," MAINE / ME /"])
s = "CENTRAL MAINE MEDICAL CENTER"

x = [re.findall(r'(?:{}).*?\/\s*(\w+)'.format(i), grp) for i in s.split()]
print(' '.join([j for i in x for j in i]))

# Result
CTR ME MED CTR
```

RegEx Explanation:

```
(                        // start of group 
  ?:                     // non-capture group
  SEARCH_WORD            // matches the search word
)                        // end of group
.*?                      // matches any character lazily
\/                       // matches a forward slash /
\s*                      // matches 0 or more whitespace characters
(                        // start of capture group 
  \w+                    // matches 1 or more word characters
)                        // end of capture group
```

Comment: Ok, now it matches for the sample output. But I think OP wants to preserve the rest of the sentence. For example, the input `Welcome to CENTRAL MAINE MEDICAL CENTER, enjoy your stay` should produce the output `Welcome to CTR ME MED CTR, enjoy your stay`.

Comment: That's why my input differed the first time, was going to suggest using the regex to create a dictionary to replace with.  Either way, he needs to post clearer requirements if that is his end goal.

Comment: well this solution is helpful and its working in python 2.7, when i tried in 2.6.6 getting ValueError: zero length field name in format

Comment: @chrisz As you said its overlapping if search iteration more than once, how can we avoid overlapping?

Comment: You would have to change `grp` to avoid overlapping, since lots of words can map to the same abbreviation.